# How can I make a texture repeat?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am making a dragon and the texture is scales. I need to repeat the texture so that the scales look a decent size. I am quite new to Blender so I'm sorry if this is obvious.

I am using Blender 2.83

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMPjKVgTfYs&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6&index=18

Comment: your question is a bit too broad, but maybe for this kind of stack you should look into some tutorials about the Texture Painting > Stencil

Answer (score 0):

To have bigger scales set the texture's X and Y size, in the mapping section, to the value between 0 and 1, e.g 0.5 Repeat is necessary only with values bigger than 1.